# similar pubmed articles via pubmed api

Tags: pubmed

Is it possible to obtain similar pubmed articles given a pmid. Example this [link](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26998445) shows similar articles on the rights hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with BioPython using the [NCBI API](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/). The command you are looking for is `neighbor_score`. Alternatively you can get the data directly via the [URL](https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/elink.fcgi?dbfrom=pubmed&db=pubmed&id=26998445&cmd=neighbor_score).

```
from Bio import Entrez

Entrez.email = "Your.Name.Here@example.org"
handle = Entrez.elink(db="pubmed", id="26998445", cmd="neighbor_score", rettype="xml")
records = Entrez.read(handle)

scores = sorted(records[0]['LinkSetDb'][0]['Link'], key=lambda k: int(k['Score']))
#show the top 5 results
for i in range(1, 6):
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=scores[-i]['Id'], rettype="xml")
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    print(record)
```

Comment: Thanks I will have a look.

Comment: Do you know how to interpret the score?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I treat them as arbitrary numbers which only make sense in the context of the whole list. Perhaps you can find the true meaning somewhere in the original publication: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2212667/